# Saving video file in a Specific Folder : Windows Form Application C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey guys uhm well as you can see i'm having trouble saving a video file because some answers in some threads here doesn't suggest that a video file should be saved in a database because it will only prolong the process, so the point here is that i'm trying to save a video file from a specific folder. im not that used to "savefiledialog" function  yet but i'm doing reseaches about it,

i just need to know if it is possible to create the same video file and save it as a new copy with a different name using savefiledialog.

[Here's the sample of my form pre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw03a.png)

thanks for your response guys if there's one

Comment: Do you want to copy a file to a destination? `System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination)`

Comment: do i have to specify the file name in the source?

Comment: Yes, you should specify the file name both in source and destination.

Comment: one more question :D is it possible just to save it without the destination as if it is a new rendered video since i selected it and previewed it in my form.
because the given code is in static form? can i do it dynamically? 

thanks for answering by the way!

Comment: When you want to copy a file you should pass both source and destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`System.IO.File.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy file from a source to destination. For example:

```
var sourceFile=@"d:\video.avi";
var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
//You can offer a default name
saveFileDialog.FileName = "video-copy.avi";
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, saveFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

If destination file exists, you will receive an exception. You can check for file existence using `System.IO.File.Exists` or you can overwrite the destination file using `System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination, true)`.